# Remove duplicate based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

My table value:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2 COLUMN3
WF1      Email   1640
WF1      Email   1641
WF1      Email   N/A
WF3      Email   N/A
```

Expected Result:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2 COLUMN3
WF1      Email   1640
WF3      Email   N/A
```

I need to retrieve all records which column2 = 'Email' and if column1 contains duplicate value, i have to choose the record which column3 <> 'N/A'.

I read tutorial about partition by but still not sure how to get the result.

Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
    (

     COLUMN1 varchar2(20), 
     COLUMN2 varchar2(20), 
     COLUMN3 varchar2(20) 
    );

INSERT INTO TABLE1
(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
VALUES
('WF1', 'Email', '1640');

INSERT INTO TABLE1
(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
VALUES
('WF1', 'Email', '1641');

INSERT INTO TABLE1
(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
VALUES
('WF1', 'Email', 'N/A');

INSERT INTO TABLE1
(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
VALUES
('WF3', 'Email', 'N/A');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
from(
SELECT column1, column2, column3,
row_number() over (partition BY column1, column2 ORDER BY CASE WHEN column3 = 'N/A' THEN 999999999 ELSE to_number(column3) END ) rn
FROM table1)
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b090a/9)

Comment: This just solved several hours of hair pulling for me... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1,column2,max(case when column3 = 'N/A' then '0' else column3 end) column3
from table1
group by column1,column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If column1 can be not unique in the result:

```
select column1, column3 from table1 t1 
where column3 != 'N/A' or 
column3 = 'N/A' and not exists
(select * from table1 t2 
where t2.column1 = t1.column1 and t2.column3 != 'N/A')
```

If column1 must be unique in the result:

```
select column1, column3 from table1 t1 
where column3 != 'N/A' and not exists
(select * from table1 t2 
where t2.column1 = t1.column1 and t2.column3 != 'N/A' and 
to_number(t2.column3, '9999') > to_number(t1.column3, '9999')
) union 
select column1, column3 from table1 t1 
where column3 = 'N/A' and not exists 
(select * from table1 t2 where t2.column1 = t1.column1 and t2.column3 != 'N/A')
```

Note that we use union instead of union all.